# Decomposition of the covariance matrix over two orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, covariance

Let $\Sigma$ be a covariance matrix of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given two orthogonal subspaces $B, B_\perp$ (such that $dim(B) + dim(B_\perp) = n$), is it possible to decompose $\Sigma = \Sigma_B + \Sigma_{B_\perp}$? I.e, a decomposition that separates between the contribution of each subspace to the total covariance?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of decomposition would you expect? $\Sigma$ is not uniquely determined by its restriction to $B$ and $B^\perp$. How would you distinguish eg. $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ on $B=\langle e_1 \rangle$?

Comment: I don't have anything concrete in mind, but was wondering if any such decomposition is possible. Could you elaborate on "not uniquely determined by its restriction to $B$ and $B_\perp$"? What if we limited ourselves to the diagonal of the covariance matrix (the variances)?